# Keyboard shortcuts for chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, keyboard-shortcuts

Yes, I know there's a script for that. But I think it's useful enough to be inserted into the live chat for everyone.

The following keyboard shortcuts are incredibly useful:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> - For replying to messages (each Ctrl+Arrow should change the `:[message ID]` in the chat input.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> - For retrying a failed message, or <kbd>ESC</kbd> to cancel it. There should also be a keyboard shortcut to edit a failed message as per the newest functionality (Maybe the <kbd>Down</kbd> key?)

Using a chat with only the keyboard is very useful, it will be especially appreciated on chats with a more technical nature.

Comment: also, if "fixed font" button is pressed, it would be cool to have the textarea having a font-family:monospace; too

Comment: I bet the super-cool author of that script would even totally help do the integration.

Comment: `Ctrl + arrow` is usually preset on OS X. Rather use `Alt + arrow`. (Comment-crosspost from duplicate to here)